# Returning an array with time intervals between hours

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to return an array with time intervals between 4 periods:

Like, index 0 would be the interval between 8am and 10am, index 1 between 10:30 and 12:00 and so on.

I tried doing something like this using setHours method but it didn't work:

```
getPeriod() {
    let time = new Date();
    const periods = [];
    periods[0] = time >= time.setHours(8) && time <= time.setHours(10);
}
```

It seems that I cannot use >= and <= operators with Date, so I'm getting a little bit confused on how to do it.

I need the hours interval specified and stringified, but they won't change.

The time intervals will be always these ones: 8 to 10, 10:30 to 12:00, 13:30 to 15:30 and 15:30 to 18:00

Hope that someone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't mutate the variable you are currently doing comparisons on. Are you ultimately trying to store an array of actual time intervals? String literals? What is your expected/desired result object shape?

Comment: Yes, string literals, I expect something like periods[0] = "8:00-10:00" or something like that. But I still have to guarantee that the hours are correct somehow. Sorry If I wasn't very clear.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with simply hardcoding the 4 string literals in the array then? Or are you looking for a dynamic solution? Something where the start & duration of each interval is specified and stringified? I think you should update your question with your requirements and/or restrictions, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I need the start and end of the interval specified and stringified. The hours intervals won't change. I'll edit my question.

Comment: I guess it still isn't clear why you can't simply return `["8:00-10:00", "10:30-12:30", "13:30-15:30", "15:30-18:00"]` as you say the intervals won't change and will always be the same ones.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right since I'm not receiving any parameters on my function and the hours won't change dynamically. I'll think a little bit more about it, but thanks for your help!